# Why does Raster Calculator return GRID ERROR-Unable to open input grid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I'm calculating Simple Ratio (SR) from NDVI using Raster calculator in Arcgis. Here is expression I wrote in Raster calculator.

```
SR=(1+float[NDVI_apr.tif])/(1-float[NDVI_apr.tif])
```

But when I evaluate this expression, the following error always appear on the screen.

```
GRID ERROR-Unable to open the input grid: 1+FLOATC:\document\... 
Error in executing grid expression.
```

What is wrong with this expression?

Comment: are you giving spaces between all operators? ( 1 + float[NDVI_apr.tif] ) / ( 1 - float[NDVI_apr.tif] )

Comment: Yes, I did. But result is the same, showing me the above error. The NDVI_apr.tif image is raster image. I want to ask 2 things. 1. Can the raster image be used directly in raster calculator in Arcgis. I read it can, but I'm not sure. Or Is it necessary to convert it into grid. 2. The NDVI image is in D disk on my computer (not in GIS working directory). Is it ok?

Comment: Doesn't Float need a capital F in Raster Calculator as per example [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000zn000000.htm)?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can calculate the SR from an NDVI.  Isn't the simple ratio nIR/red?

Answer (score 2):

write your expression using raster calculator buttons . don't write / + - * using pc or laptop keyboard.

your expression must be like this :

```
sr =(1 + Float("NDVI_apr.tif")) / (1 - Float("NDVI_apr.tif"))
```

this expression work properly in ArcGIS 10

Answer (score 1):

Float appears to need a capital F in Raster Calculator as per example [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000zn000000.htm) which is probably why @wetland Answer has expression working.